# Why Does Getting WebView by ID crash at runtime?

Tags: android, webview, android-activity

I'm seeing a application failure when trying to show a webview in an activity.  It does work if i instantiate the webview in onCreate() though, rather than getting R.id.webview.  Why would that be?

Here's the activity to showing the web view:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.id.webview);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");        
    }
```

Layout xml file:

```
<WebView  
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Comment: There is no layout to look inside. Change the `setContentView()` param to the layout file

Comment: `setContentView(R.id.webview);`? maybe layout that contains the `webview`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn the comments into an answer:

```
setContentView(R.id.webview);
```

You don't pass a view id to this method but a layout file. You can then access your view contained inside that layout with `findViewById(R.id.webview)`
So supply it the layout xml file instead.

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_webview_layout);
```

Or whatever your layout is called.

Also in the future your should attach your logcat log to your question if it is logging error and exceptions. It identifies the type of problem and the location in your code it is occurring/triggered. When doing that also indicate which line(s) in your posted code it is referencing.